# Barcode scanning in xamarin forms

Tags: asp.net, xamarin.forms

In xamarin does anybody know how to capture image after scanning the barcode or qrcode using MobileBarcodeScanner? I am getting the proper scanned barcode or qrcode in text format. But can I get the scanned image from it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that ZXing exposes the underlying image data it uses for scanning.  If you need this behavior it would probably be fairly easy to modify ZXing to do it.

Answer (score 0):

ZXing does not support returns scanned image.

You would need to modify the ZXing source code.

I found solution from Xamarin forum, read this.

- [ZXing get scanned picture - Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21906/zxing-get-scanned-picture)

Quote from this thread as follows.

> At the Result.cs class, add properties to handle width, height and source image
>
> ```
> public Android.Graphics.YuvImage SourceYuv { get; set; }
> public int SourceWidth  { get; set; }
> public int SourceHeight  { get; set; }
> ```
>
> in ZXingSurfaceView.cs modify the OnPreviewFrame method to save the raw image
>
> ```
> ...at the beginning before the processing
> var img = new YuvImage(bytes, ImageFormatType.Nv21, cameraParameters.PreviewSize.Width, cameraParameters.PreviewSize.Height, null);
> ...result calculations...
> result.SourceWidth = width;
> result.SourceHeight = height;
> result.SourceYuv = img;
> ```
>
> later in our own code when we get the results we can easily save it to a file or do whatever we want
>
> ```
>     string filenamefile = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".jpg";
>     string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(Values.DownloadsFolder(), filenamefile);
>     Android.Graphics.Rect rect = new Android.Graphics.Rect(0, 0, result.SourceWidth, result.SourceHeight); 
>
>     using (var os = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.CreateNew))
>     {
>              result.SourceYuv.CompressToJpeg(rect, 100, os);
>              os.Flush();
>                  os.Close();
>      }
> ```